# Append Child Element on reset - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to reset the game by appending child element back to '1'. By default in html it is labelled as 1 and on finishing game it gets to empty but when this bonus life is used i want at the end of the game to be reset to '1'.

```js
<h2>PLAYER HEALTH<span id="bonus-life">1</span></h2>
```

I have used this function in JavaScript but seem to be not working:

```js
function resetBonus() {
    bonusLifeEl.parentNode.appendChild(bonusLifeEl);
}
```

This function is called in a file which is like this:

```js
if (currentMonsterHealth <= 0 || currentPlayerHealth <= 0) {
    reset();
    resetBonus();
}
```

Reset function just remove bonus life

```js
function reset() {
    currentMonsterHealth = chosenMaxLife;
    currentPlayerHealth = chosenMaxLife;
    resetGame(chosenMaxLife);
}
```

Comment: How do you define `bonusLifeEl`?

Comment: `const bonusLifeEl = document.getElementById('bonus-life');`

Answer (score 0):

```
function resetBonus() {
    bonusLifeEl.innerHTML = bonusLifeEl;
}
```

Comment: This is what I am getting now on UI.  ' PLAYER HEALTH[object HTMLSpanElement]' that value in brace instead of 1 becoming as in the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will be changed when you try to add a child to the parent where it is already exists.

You can change the value instead of add/remove child by `innerText` or `innerHTML` values.